# running VSP as SSH command on HP ilo5 hung

Tags: console, serial-console, hp, virtual-consoles

I am trying to do a little automation to VSP on HP ilo5. While I can successfully SSH into the ilo and I can run vsp from hpiLO-> prompt I cannot run it directly from remote host as part of SSH command.

This works: as some user:

```
$ ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -t hpserver

User:user logged-in to hpserver
Integrated Lights-Out 5
iLO Advanced 2.65 at  Feb 23 2022
Server Name: hpserver
Server Power: On

</>hpiLO->
</>hpiLO->vsp
Virtual Serial Port Active: COM1

Starting virtual serial port.
Press 'ESC (' to return to the CLI Session.


Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8
Kernel 4....

hpserver login:
```

(at this point I can give uid and **works just fine**.)

while this fails, it does not take keyboard commands and seem to be hung:

```
$ ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -t hpserver vsp

vsp
Virtual Serial Port Active: COM1

Starting virtual serial port.
Press 'ESC (' to return to the CLI Session.


Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8
Kernel 4....

hpserver login:
```

(**hung**.... no keyboard keystroke works...)

Does anyone know how to fix this? (I have removed MOTD from above output.)